# Cannot get $anchorScroll to work properly with scrollspy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scrollspy

Right now I am working on something with angularJS and Bootstrap and for some reason I can't set the offset in $anchorScroll or scrollspy. Right now I am focusing on trying to get $anchorScroll working.

```
    $anchorScroll.yOffset = 300;
    $scope.gotoAnchor = function(x) {
        console.log("x: ", x);
        var newHash = x;
        if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
            // set the $location.hash to `newHash` and
            // $anchorScroll will automatically scroll to it
            $location.hash(x);
        } else {
            // call $anchorScroll() explicitly,
            // since $location.hash hasn't changed
            $anchorScroll();
        }
    };
```

But for some reason my yOffset is just ignored! How do I fix this? Why is it being ignored?

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) `$anchorScroll.yOffset = 300;` should be set inside angular `run()` method not in the controller code which I assume you are doing.

Comment: In this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TDF0D7?p=preview) it works inside a contoller. The [original plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/k5DCMwxGQ0lmcDSvVGcl?p=preview) does do that though.